# Converting from 7-speed to 10-speed rear wheel

Tags: drivetrain, wheel-building

My Bridgestone MB-5 currently has a 7-speed rear wheel. I'd like to convert it to a 10-speed. Is this possible? Is it practical?

Comment: What is 7 x 1.5? What is wheel casket? 2 x 10 sounds like a drivetrain.

Comment: Yes, you need to clarify.  Are you talking about changing the sprocket cluster ("cassette") on the wheel?  If so, what change precisely are you proposing?

Comment: right now i'm running a 2x8 set up my cassette is 7. my sifters are a shimano sora 8x3 . May be all I need to to find some older road bike derailluer sp that are 3x8 ?

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in this .. [The 1992 Bridgestone catalogue](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_14377075766719&drKey=1050&libId=ich1ygve01000er2000DAdyzstbsb&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bikeforums.net%2Fclassic-vintage%2F49577-bridgestone-mb-5-a.html&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sheldonbrown.com%2Fbridgestone%2F1992%2F1992.pdf&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.nz&title=bridgestone%20mb-5&txt=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sheldonbrown.com%2Fbridgestone%2F1992%2F1992.pdf) (8meg PDF)

The bike is the lower end of the range (MB-6 being lowest), meaning its not worth that much and never started out as a great bike. As its steel (one redeeming feature), its possible to cold form the frame to widen the rear drop outs to take a 10speed, so technically its possible......

Practically its not worth it. The bike is old and low end. To upgrade to 10Speed you would need

- Complete Wheel (at least a new Hub and cassette)
- Dérailleur
- Shifters
- Chain rings

Probably

- Shifter Cables
- Chain